# displaying the data from a database table and hiding the null values alone

Tags: mysql

I have created a table named `subjects` which contains an `id` column as primary key and 10  subject columns (`subject1,subject2,....subject10`).

Now for a specific `id` there may be 5, 8 or 10 `subjects`. The `id` which has 5 `subjects` is left out as `null` value for remaining 5 `subject` and vice versa for id with 8 `subjects`.

Please help me with the queries for retrieval from database, such that if a row is selected an id that has 5 subjects, during retrieval the remaining 5 `null` values should be made hidden.

Comment: Please write your question in a way that is readable and comprehensible. Also, post the data structure of your tables instead of describing them. We understand code not what you think

Comment: Do you want to have for example a "user" have multiple "subject"'s? If so, your database structure is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

You should rethink your database structure and create 3 tables. Lets assume you want to have a user that is linked to one or more subjects. You could model your database like this:

**User**

- UserId
- ...

**UserToSubject**

- UserId
- SubjectId

**Subject**

- SubjectId
- ...

The User table will contain any information about the user, the Subject table will contain information about each subject, and the UserToSubject table is used to link multiple users to multiple subjects (a many-to-many relationship).

Then you can proceed to get the values by using `JOIN`:

```
SELECT
  u.UserId
  s.SubjectID
FROM
  User u
  JOIN UserToSubject uts ON u.UserId = uts.UserId
  JOIN Subject s ON s.SubjectId = uts.SubjectId
GROUP BY
  u.UserId
```

Of course, your User table can be anything, as long as it is identifying something.